# Causal Diagram with a Common Grandchild

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, tikz-trees

I want to make the following diagram type, but with a vertical orientation (Common Grandchild Horizontal):

[image: Common Grandchild Horizontal]

Specifically, I want the 3 children from my diagram to end up having a common grandchild. So far, I have the following code but do not know how to draw the common grandchild:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,eurosym,geometry,ulem,graphicx,caption,subcaption, color,setspace,sectsty,comment,footmisc,caption,natbib,pdflscape,subfigure,array, enumerate, natbib, indentfirst, float, tikz, rotating, lipsum, adjustbox, booktabs, multirow, soul, changepage,threeparttable}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}



\usepackage[unicode, bookmarks, colorlinks, breaklinks]{hyperref}  

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, pdfstartview=FitV, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=black, plainpages=false, pdfpagelabels=true, urlcolor=blue}


\usepackage[nameinlink, capitalise, noabbrev]{cleveref}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}} %Citation-related commands

\normalem

\onehalfspacing
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{conj}{Conjecture}

\newenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\noindent\textbf{#1.} }{\ \rule{0.5em}{0.5em}}

\newtheorem{hyp}{Hypothesis}
\newtheorem{subhyp}{Hypothesis}[hyp]
\renewcommand{\thesubhyp}{\thehyp\alph{subhyp}}

\newcommand{\red}[1]{{\color{red} #1}}
\newcommand{\blue}[1]{{\color{blue} #1}}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\geometry{left=1.0in,right=1.0in,top=1.0in,bottom=1.0in}


\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,intersections,arrows.meta,shadows,positioning}
\newcommand{\FixedLengthArrow}{2,0}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  sibling distance=6cm,
  edge from parent/.append style={->},
  growth parent anchor=south,
  >=Latex
]

% root of the the initial tree, level 1
\node [root] (root) {Grandpa}
  % The first level, as children of the initial tree

    child {node {Father}  
      child {node (C1){Child}}
      child {node (C2) {Child}}
      child {node (C3) {Child}}
  }

    
\path (root-1-1-1.south)  -- coordinate (midway)   (root-1-1-1.south) ;


  
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Common Grandchild} 
\label{fig: Causal}
\end{figure}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (that is: place the semicolons at the right places) and only put those packages and definitions in your example that are needed to produce your problem (or diagram in this case).

Comment: Just connect the grandchild only to the middle node first, then connect it manually to the other two children using `\draw`.

Answer (score 3):

This way?

Since you didn't specify the style `root`, I invented the node style.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=1.0in,right=1.0in,top=1.0in,bottom=1.0in}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,intersections,arrows.meta,shadows,positioning}

\usepackage[unicode, bookmarks, colorlinks, breaklinks]{hyperref}  
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, pdfstartview=FitV, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=black, plainpages=false, pdfpagelabels=true, urlcolor=blue}

\normalem

\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  sibling distance=6cm,
  edge from parent/.append style={->},
  growth parent anchor=south,
  >=Latex,
  nodes={draw, fill=cyan,
      text width=3cm,
      text centered}
]
% root of the the initial tree, level 1
\node (root) {Grandpa}
  % The first level, as children of the initial tree
    child {node {Father}  
      child {node (C1) {Child}}
      child {node (C2) {Child}
        child {node (C21) {Grand child}}
        }
      child {node (C3) {Child}}
  };
  \draw [->] (C1) -- (C21)
    (C3) -- (C21);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Common Grandchild} 
\label{fig: Causal}
\end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With use of `forest` package:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}

\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{arr/.style = {draw=cyan, semithick, -{Triangle[angle=45:1pt 3]} },
  every edge/.style = {arr} }


\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes
    draw=cyan, fill=cyan!30,
    minimum size=2.4ex, anchor=center,
% tree
    grow'=south,
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    l sep=7mm,
    s sep=3mm,
    edge = {arr},
    }
[Grandpa
    [Father 
        [Child, name=A]
        [Child,
            [Grand Child, name=C]
        ]
        [Child, name=B]
    ]
]
\path   (A)  edge (C) 
        (B)  edge (C);
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: forest]

**Edit:**
As response to your comment.

Package `forest`  is dedicated for advance drawing of trees. Based is on `tikz` package (which it also load)  and can use elemets from it.

For test of code for drawings some image, is handing to use `standalone` package. Code, developed by its use, can be simply copied to your document, for example in your case:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{arr/.style = {draw=cyan, semithick, -{Triangle[angle=45:1pt 3]} },
  every edge/.style = {arr} 
        }
        
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text filler        


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
   \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes
    draw=cyan, fill=cyan!30,
    minimum size=2.4ex, anchor=center,
% tree
    grow'=south,
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    l sep=7mm,
    s sep=3mm,
    edge = {arr},
    }
[Grandpa
    [Father
        [Child, name=A]
        [Child,
            [Grand Child, name=C]
        ]
        [Child, name=B]
    ]
]
\path   (A)  edge (C)
        (B)  edge (C);
    \end{forest}
\caption{Common Grandchild}
\label{fig: Causal}
    \end{figure} 

\lipsum[1][4-7]

\end{document}
```

Wwhich gives

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. How could I insert the forest tree in a figure environment, with a caption to cite it? I think the forest tree package is much friendlier than the TIKZ.

Comment: @AntonioSmithBravo, ah,  I focused only on image (I was sure, that incapsulate image code to `figure` environment is not a problem). It is simple: in `figure` you insert code from `\begin{forest}` to `\end{forest}`, than add caption and label. That is all. Of course, to your document preamble you need to add preamble content from my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am having the following problem though: when I insert the figure environment, suddenly all the boxes disappear and I only see the text with arrows. In addition, I see the following text:                                                                
   for tree = 
% nodes
    draw=cyan, fill=cyan!30,
    minimum size=2.4ex, anchor=center,
% tree
    grow'=south,
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    l sep=7mm,
    s sep=3mm,
    edge = {arr},
It did not recognize the command when I inserted the image. Could you help me?