# Causal diagram with many grandchildren and great-grandchildren

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, tikz-trees

[Causal Diagram with a Common Grandchild](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/623390/causal-diagram-with-a-common-grandchild/623546?noredirect=1#comment1556624_623546)

How do I add a grand grandchild to the bottom? What about if I want to add 3 grand-grandchild and then one common grand-grand-grandchild as you did above?

Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Here the grand children and the common great grand child:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=1.0in,right=1.0in,top=1.0in,bottom=1.0in}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,intersections,arrows.meta,shadows,positioning}

\usepackage[unicode, bookmarks, colorlinks, breaklinks]{hyperref}  
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, pdfstartview=FitV, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=black, plainpages=false, pdfpagelabels=true, urlcolor=blue}

\normalem

\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  sibling distance=6cm,
  edge from parent/.append style={->},
  growth parent anchor=south,
  >=Latex,
  nodes={draw, fill=cyan,
      text width=4cm,
      text centered}
]
% root of the the initial tree, level 1
\node (root) {Grandpa}
  % The first level, as children of the initial tree
    child {node {Father}  
      child {node (C1) {Child}
        child {node (C11) {Grand child}}}
      child {node (C2) {Child}
        child {node (C21) {Grand child}
        child {node (C211) {Grand grand child}}}
        }
      child {node (C3) {Child}
        child {node (C31) {Grand child}}}
  };
  \draw [->] (C31) -- (C211);
  \draw [->] (C11) -- (C211);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Common Grandchild} 
\label{fig: Causal}
\end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tried to do the same but cannot place the grandchild and the grand-grandchild in the middle of the diagram. Could you help me? Here is the link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/623695/moving-a-box-in-a-forest-tree-diagram-to-the-middle