# Moving a box in a forest tree diagram to the middle

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, tikz-trees

Could you help me place the grandchild and grand-grandchild in the middle of the diagram? How could I do it? I also notice that when I try to add a fourth grandchild or child, the graph does not fit in a page? Is there a command to make everything fit and be centered?

`````
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,eurosym,geometry,ulem,graphicx,caption,subcaption, color,setspace,sectsty,comment,footmisc,caption,natbib,pdflscape,subfigure,array, enumerate, natbib, indentfirst, float, tikz, rotating, lipsum, adjustbox, booktabs, multirow, soul, changepage,threeparttable}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}



\usepackage[unicode, bookmarks, colorlinks, breaklinks]{hyperref}  

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, pdfstartview=FitV, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=black, plainpages=false, pdfpagelabels=true, urlcolor=blue}


\usepackage[nameinlink, capitalise, noabbrev]{cleveref}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}} %Citation-related commands

\normalem

\onehalfspacing
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{conj}{Conjecture}

\newenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\noindent\textbf{#1.} }{\ \rule{0.5em}{0.5em}}

\newtheorem{hyp}{Hypothesis}
\newtheorem{subhyp}{Hypothesis}[hyp]
\renewcommand{\thesubhyp}{\thehyp\alph{subhyp}}

\newcommand{\red}[1]{{\color{red} #1}}
\newcommand{\blue}[1]{{\color{blue} #1}}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\geometry{left=1.0in,right=1.0in,top=1.0in,bottom=1.0in}


\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,intersections,arrows.meta,shadows,positioning}
\newcommand{\FixedLengthArrow}{2,0}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
  block/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=yellow, text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2em},
  line/.style = {draw, -latex'},
}


\tikzset{
  basic/.style={
    draw,
    text width=3cm, 
    drop shadow, 
    font=\sffamily
  },
  root/.style={
    basic, 
    rounded corners=2pt, 
    thin, 
    align=center,
    fill=green!30
  },
  child node/.style={
    basic, 
    rounded corners=6pt, 
    thin,
    align=center, 
    fill=green!60,
    text width=10em,
    anchor=north
  },
  every child node/.style={child node}
}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  sibling distance=6cm,
  edge from parent/.append style={->},
  growth parent anchor=south,
  >=Latex,
  nodes={draw, fill=cyan,
      text width=4cm,
      text centered}
]
% root of the the initial tree, level 1
\node (root) {Oil Wealth}
  % The first level, as children of the initial tree
    
    child {node (A1)  {Grandparent}  
        child {node (B1) {Parent}
            child {node (C11) {Child}}
            child {node (C12) {Child}}
            child {node (C13) {Child}}}}
    
 
      child {node (D11) {Grandchild}}  
      child {node (D12) {Grandchild}}  
      
      child {node (E12) {Grand-Grandchild}}      
                      
            
    
       
        ;
  \draw [->] (C11) -- (D11);
  \draw [->] (C12) -- (D11);
  \draw [->] (C11) -- (D12);
  \draw [->] (C12) -- (D12);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Mine Editing Tex III} 
\label{fig: Causal}
\end{figure}  


\end{document} ````
`````

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. Please also add only the needed packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Please provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document, which begin with `\documentclass[...]{...}` and end with `\end{document}, and which has in preamble loaded *only* to your problem relates packages anddefined new commands or environments.
- Try to avoid to use `[H]` floats position placement. It prevent that floats can float (they lost most important features). Consequently this often lead to (very) bad typography. Rather use `[htb]`

**Original answer:**

If I correctly understood what you after, then the following `tikz` solution is what you after:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,intersections,arrows.meta,shadows,positioning}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
  block/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=yellow, text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2em},
  line/.style = {draw, -latex'},
}

\tikzset{
  basic/.style={
    draw,
    text width=3cm,
    drop shadow,
    font=\sffamily
  },
  root/.style={
    basic,
    rounded corners=2pt,
    thin,
    align=center,
    fill=green!30
  },
  child node/.style={
    basic,
    rounded corners=6pt,
    thin,
    align=center,
    fill=green!60,
    text width=10em,
    anchor=north
  },
  every child node/.style={child node}
}

    \begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  sibling distance=6cm,
  edge from parent/.append style={->},
  growth parent anchor=south,
  >=Latex,
  nodes={draw, fill=cyan,
      text width=4cm,
      text centered}
]
% root of the the initial tree, level 1
\node (root) {Oil Wealth}
  % The first level, as children of the initial tree
    child {node (A1)  {Grandparent}
        child {node (B1) {Parent}
            child {node (C11) {Child 1}
                   child {node (D12) {Grandchild}}
                   }
            child {node (C12) {Child 2}
                   child {node (D11) {Grandchild}}
                   }
            child {node (C13) {Child 3}
                   child {node (D12) {Grandchild}
                          child {node (E12) {Grand-Grandchild}}
                   }}}
        };
  \draw [->] (C11) -- (D11);
  \draw [->] (C12) -- (D11);
  \draw [->] (C11) -- (D12);
  \draw [->] (C12) -- (D12);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Mine Editing Tex III}
\label{fig: Causal}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit (1):**
However, use of `forest` package for drawing your tree make code much shorter and simple :-)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                shadows}
\tikzset{arr/.style = {draw, -{Stealth[length=2mm]}},
  every edge/.style = {arr}
        }

\usepackage{lipsum}             % for dummy text filler

\begin{document}
\section{Tree}\label{sec6}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
    \begin{forest}
for tree={
% nodes
    draw, semithick, rounded corners,
    fill=green!39, drop shadow,
    text width=7em, text centered,
    font=\sffamily,
% tree
    s sep = 4mm,
    l sep = 13mm,
     edge = {arr},
        }
[Oil Wealth, fill=cyan, sharp corners
    [Grandparent 
        [Parent
            [Child 1, name=A1
                [Grandchild]
            ]
            [Child 2, name=A2
                [Grandchild, name=B2]
            ]
            [Child 3
                [Grandchild, name=B3
                    [Grand-Grandchild]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\draw   (A1) edge (B2)
        (A1) edge (B3)
        (A2) edge (B3);  
    \end{forest}
\caption{Mine Editing Tex III}
\label{fig: Causal}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit (2):**
I test your image code again. That I can see whole image on the page, I reduce its size size to 0.7 of original image. Result was the following:

[image]

Sorry, but from this image is almost impossible to see, what you like to have. To clarify, what is your problem, you should provide a sketch of desired result or at least link to your predecessor questions and answers which probably solve your problems (so far you not accept any of them. Are all of them wrong?). This would make guessing simpler ...

Now I guessing, inspired by @Carlatex answer, that you may looking for something like this:

[image]

MWE, which use `forest` package, for above image is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                shadows}
\tikzset{arr/.style = {draw, -{Stealth[length=2mm]}},
  every edge/.style = {arr}
        }

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
    \begin{forest}
for tree={
% nodes
    draw, semithick, rounded corners,
    fill=green!39, drop shadow,
    text width=7em, text centered,
    font=\sffamily,
% tree
    s sep = 4mm,
    l sep = 13mm,
     edge = {arr},
        }
[Oil Wealth, fill=cyan, sharp corners
    [Grandparent 
        [Parent
            [Child 1, name=A1
                [Grandchild 1]
            ]
            [Child 2, 
                [Grandchild 2, name=B2
                    [Grand-Grandchild]
                ]
            ]
            [Child 3, name=A3
                [Grandchild 3, name=B3]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\draw   (A1) edge (B2)
        (A3) edge (B2);  
    \end{forest}
\caption{Mine Editing Tex III}
\label{fig: Causal}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Is this what you looking for?

Comment: Thank you very much. The forest package is much easier to understand! This was what I was looking for.

Comment: @AntonioSmithBravo, it is nice to hear, that we guess correctly, what you after. So, now you can accept answer, which is most useful for you (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer). So far you not accept any of answers received on your question. By this you inform community that your question is still not solved ...

Comment: @Zarko in the `Edit(1)` above at node `A2` will it be `chold 2` or `Child 2`

Comment: @jsbibra, you are right. A terrible typing error. :-(. I would corrected it ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

It is very difficult to understand what you need.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,eurosym,geometry,ulem,graphicx,caption,subcaption, color,setspace,sectsty,comment,footmisc,
%caption, DO NOT LOAD PACKAGES TWICE
natbib,pdflscape,
%subfigure, subfigure is incompatible with subcaption and you already loaded subcaption
array, enumerate, %natbib,  DO NOT LOAD PACKAGES TWICE
indentfirst, float, tikz, rotating, lipsum, adjustbox, booktabs, multirow, soul, changepage,threeparttable}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}



\usepackage[unicode, bookmarks, colorlinks, breaklinks]{hyperref}  

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, pdfstartview=FitV, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=black, plainpages=false, pdfpagelabels=true,
    urlcolor=blue}


\usepackage[nameinlink, capitalise, noabbrev]{cleveref}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}} %Citation-related commands

\normalem

\onehalfspacing
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{conj}{Conjecture}

\newenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\noindent\textbf{#1.} }{\ \rule{0.5em}{0.5em}}

\newtheorem{hyp}{Hypothesis}
\newtheorem{subhyp}{Hypothesis}[hyp]
\renewcommand{\thesubhyp}{\thehyp\alph{subhyp}}

\newcommand{\red}[1]{{\color{red} #1}}
\newcommand{\blue}[1]{{\color{blue} #1}}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\geometry{left=1.0in,right=1.0in,top=1.0in,bottom=1.0in}


\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,intersections,arrows.meta,shadows,positioning}
\newcommand{\FixedLengthArrow}{2,0}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
  block/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=yellow, text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2em},
  line/.style = {draw, -latex'},
}


\tikzset{
  basic/.style={
    draw,
    text width=3cm, 
    drop shadow, 
    font=\sffamily
  },
  root/.style={
    basic, 
    rounded corners=2pt, 
    thin, 
    align=center,
    fill=green!30
  },
  child node/.style={
    basic, 
    rounded corners=6pt, 
    thin,
    align=center, 
    fill=green!60,
    text width=10em,
    anchor=north
  },
  every child node/.style={child node}
}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  sibling distance=6cm,
  edge from parent/.append style={->},
  growth parent anchor=south,
  >=Latex,
  nodes={draw, fill=cyan,
      text width=4cm,
      text centered}
]
% root of the the initial tree, level 1
\node (root) {Oil Wealth}
  % The first level, as children of the initial tree
    
    child {
        node (A1)  {Grandparent}  
        child {
            node (B1) {Parent}
            child {
                node (C11) {Child}  
                child {
                   node (D11) {Grandchild}}}
            child {node (C12) {Child} 
                child {
                    node (D12) {Grandchild}
                    child {node (E12) {Grand-Grandchild}}     
                    } 
                }
            child {node (C13) {Child}}
            }
            }
       
        ;
  \draw [->] (C11) -- (D11);
  \draw [->] (C12) -- (D11);
  \draw [->] (C11) -- (D12);
  \draw [->] (C12) -- (D12);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Mine Editing Tex III} 
\label{fig: Causal}
\end{figure}  


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Apparently may guessing is different :-). I saw one more "Grandchildren" ... Anyway +1 ...

Comment: @Zarko There is an history: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/623554/causal-diagram-with-many-grandchildren-and-great-grandchildren?noredirect=1&lq=1 Let wait for further instructions by the OP :D Thank you for the upvote

Comment: I didn't see this question and your answer.

Comment: @Zarko This one is the third :D