# Problem with Forest Tree Arrows

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I the following diagram, I have problems connecting the   (A2) with (B1)
(A3) with (B1). I cannot spot the mistake. Could you please help me?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,eurosym,geometry,ulem,graphicx,caption,subcaption, hyperref, color,setspace,sectsty,comment,footmisc,caption,natbib,pdflscape,subfigure,array, enumerate, natbib, indentfirst, float, tikz, rotating, lipsum, adjustbox, booktabs, multirow, soul, changepage,threeparttable, forest}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}



\usepackage[unicode, bookmarks, colorlinks, breaklinks]{hyperref}  

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, pdfstartview=FitV, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=black, plainpages=false, urlcolor=blue}


\usepackage[nameinlink, capitalise, noabbrev]{cleveref}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}} %Citation-related commands

\normalem

\onehalfspacing
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{conj}{Conjecture}

\newenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\noindent\textbf{#1.} }{\ \rule{0.5em}{0.5em}}

\newtheorem{hyp}{Hypothesis}
\newtheorem{subhyp}{Hypothesis}[hyp]
\renewcommand{\thesubhyp}{\thehyp\alph{subhyp}}

\newcommand{\red}[1]{{\color{red} #1}}
\newcommand{\blue}[1]{{\color{blue} #1}}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\geometry{left=1.0in,right=1.0in,top=1.0in,bottom=1.0in}


\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,intersections,arrows.meta,shadows,positioning}
\newcommand{\FixedLengthArrow}{2,0}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  basic/.style={
    draw,
    text width=3cm, 
    drop shadow, 
    font=\sffamily
  },
  root/.style={
    basic, 
    rounded corners=2pt, 
    thin, 
    align=center,
    fill=red!30
  },
  child node/.style={
    basic, 
    rounded corners=6pt, 
    thin,
    align=center, 
    fill=green!60,
    text width=10em,
    anchor=north
  },
  every child node/.style={child node}
}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shadow}


\tikzset{arr/.style = {draw, -{Stealth[length=2mm]}},
  every edge/.style = {arr}
        }

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
    \begin{forest}
for tree={
% nodes
    draw, semithick, rounded corners,
    fill=green!39, drop shadow,
    text width=10em, text centered,
    font=\sffamily,
% tree
    s sep = 2mm,
    l sep = 5mm,
     edge = {arr},
        }
[Oil Wealth, fill=cyan, sharp corners
    [DD [EE [A1, name=A1]
    
   
    
    [BB, [B1,name=B1 [FF, [CC, [DD,[EE ]]]]]]
    
    [AA, name=A3]]]
    
     [ZZ, no edge]]
    
    
\draw   (A2) edge (B1)
        (A3) edge (B1);  
        
    \end{forest}
\caption{Causal Channels}
\label{fig: Causal}

    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please consider making your MWE compilable, i.e. starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. I failed to compile it even with adding some of the necessary code lines.

Comment: What is now different from your previous question  in accepted answer . tex.stackexchange.com/questions/623695/…. You should be able on basis of accepted answer provide an really MWE, even more, extend forest code with new nodes, if they are needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you provided is certainly not a *minimal* working example and I would recommend that you make sure that you load packages only once and only those packages you really need.

You error stems primarily from two things:

1. You may not leave blank lines in the `forest` environment.
2. You cannot refer to a node when you did not define its name before.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{forest}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes, shadows, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  arr/.style={
    draw, -{Stealth[length=2mm]}
  },
}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
% nodes
    draw, semithick, rounded corners,
    fill=green!39, drop shadow,
    text width=10em, text centered,
    font=\sffamily,
% tree
    s sep = 2mm,
    l sep = 5mm,
    edge = {arr},
}
[Oil Wealth, fill=cyan, sharp corners
    [DD 
        [EE 
            [A1, name=A1]
            [BB 
                [B1, name=B1
                    [FF 
                        [CC 
                            [DD
                                [EE]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
            [AA, name=A3]
        ]
    ]
    [ZZ, no edge]
]
%
\draw[arr] (A1) edge (B1)
           (A3) edge (B1);  
% 
\end{forest}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Update**

Since the OP added a to their problem the question how to place the root node directly over node “DD”, I made a minor adjustment to the code by adding a phantom node to the left of “DD”:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{forest}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes, shadows, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  arr/.style={
    draw, -{Stealth[length=2mm]}
  },
}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
% nodes
    draw, semithick, rounded corners,
    fill=green!39, drop shadow,
    text width=10em, text centered,
    font=\sffamily,
% tree
    s sep = 2mm,
    l sep = 5mm,
    edge = {arr},
}
[Oil Wealth, fill=cyan, sharp corners
    [, phantom]
    [DD 
        [EE 
            [A1, name=A1]
            [BB 
                [B1, name=B1
                    [FF 
                        [CC 
                            [DD
                                [EE]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
            [AA, name=A3]
        ]
    ]
    [ZZ, no edge]
]
%
\draw[arr] (A1) edge (B1)
           (A3) edge (B1);  
% 
\end{forest}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

I strongly suggest a look into the [quick start guide](http://tug.ctan.org/info/forest-quickstart/forest-quickstart.pdf) to the `forest` package, which includes a lot of nice tips and tricks for different applications.

Comment: See last  last example in  in accepted answer on OP question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/623695/moving-a-box-in-a-forest-tree-diagram-to-the-middle. I don't anderstand what problem OP actually have.

Comment: Indeed! So, it is actually a duplicate. Sorry, I didn't know this.

Comment: Is not completely duplicate, your answer is just fine (+1), but I just wonder, when will OP learn something from received answers and will be able to make some small changes/extension in them for his next similar image ...

Comment: Thank you. Could you also place 'Oil Wealth' in the middle, just above 'DD'?

Comment: I am scarce in English language :-)))) thank you for your edit.

Comment: @Sebastiano I only refined your edit a bit since you edited your question in order to have it re-opened, I guess.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thank you very much. I have re-edit my question for the reopened it. However thank you and you're great also in TeX.

Comment: I just noticed that it was you who edited it =)