# Exogenous Boxes in a Forest Tree

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, tikz-trees

I want to include an arrow that connects PPP (no edge) to Pros. How could I do it? Is it possible to have an arrow between a box that does not descend from the main root and another box below? Could I add an arrow that connects Pros to a box below which descends from the common root (e.g. connect pros to "failed" for example?

Thank you

```
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{forest}
for tree={
% nodes
    draw, semithick, rounded corners,
    fill=green!39, drop shadow,
    text width=10em, text centered,
    font=\sffamily,
% tree
    s sep = 2mm,
    l sep = 5mm,
     edge = {arr},
        }
[Oil Wealth, fill=cyan, sharp corners [Societal D [Nate [IOCs , name=A1 ] [Substantial  [New]  [Government ,name=B1    [Failed, name=C1 [Opposition[Constitutional [Strong  ]]]]]]
    
    [YP , name=A3 ]]]
    
     [ppp,no edge, name=Z1 [Pros, no edge, name=Z2]]]
[Transfers ]
%

\path   (Z1)  edge (Z2) ;    
    \end{forest}


    
\caption{Causal Channels }


    \end{figure}  
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Again, the same problem as in your [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/624348/47927): *Do not* place a blank line inside the `forest` environment! Remove this empty line (before `\path (Z1) edge (Z2);`), and you will get a line between the two nodes. If you want an arrow, use `\draw[arr]` instead of `\path`.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect any node to any other node you want, regardless of whether they are part of the tree or not, as long as you give the nodes a `name`, which you already did. But you may not place an empty line inside the `forest` environment, since this will raise an error and the code will not compile (which I already mentioned in the answer to your [other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/624348/47927)).

You may want to connect the "Pros" and the "Failed" node with an arrow that does not cover the other nodes. See the example below with a suggestion on how to do this. Also, I think it would be nice to specify the `text height` and `text depth` of the nodes, since otherwise they won't align properly.

The "Transfers" node won't be printed, since it is not part of the main tree. Therefore I commented it out.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shadows}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
arr/.style={->}
}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{forest}
for tree={
% nodes
    draw, semithick, rounded corners,
    fill=green!39, drop shadow,
    text width=10em, text centered,
    font=\sffamily,
    text height=.8em,
    text depth=.1em,
% tree
    s sep = 2mm,
    l sep = 5mm,
     edge = {arr},
}
[Oil Wealth, fill=cyan, sharp corners 
    [Societal D 
        [Nate 
            [IOCs , name=A1] 
            [Substantial  
                [New]  
                [Government , name=B1
                    [Failed , name=C1 
                        [Opposition
                            [Constitutional 
                                [Strong]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
            [YP , name=A3]
        ]
    ]
    [ppp, no edge, name=Z1 
        [Pros, no edge, name=Z2]
    ]
]
% [Transfers]
%
\draw[arr] (Z1) edge (Z2);    
\draw[arr] (Z2.east) -- ++(.25,0) |- (C1.east);    
\end{forest}

\caption{Causal Channels}
\end{figure}  
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One final question. How can I add a comma to one word inside a box? I notice that the system does not allow me to add a comma, and that when I add it the word does not show up inside the box. Thank you

Comment: @AntonioSmithBravo You need to use curly braces: `[{one, word}, name=mynode]`.