# Changing the length of the arrows in a tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-trees

I want to shorten the arrows connecting each box in the following graph to fit within a page. Could you please help me?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shadows, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  basic/.style={
    draw,
    text width=3cm, 
    drop shadow, 
    font=\sffamily
  },
  root/.style={
    basic, 
    rounded corners=2pt, 
    thin, 
    align=center,
    fill=red!30
  },
  child node/.style={
    basic, 
    rounded corners=6pt, 
    thin,
    align=center, 
    fill=green!60,
    text width=10em,
    anchor=north
  },
  every child node/.style={child node}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  sibling distance=6cm,
  edge from parent/.append style={->},
  growth parent anchor=south,
  >=Latex
]

% root of the the initial tree, level 1
\node [root] (root) {Oil Wealth}
  % The first level, as children of the initial tree
  child {node {No  }
  child {node {Low }
    child {node {Strong}
         child {node {Great } 
        child {node [bottom color=blue!40]  {Strong Executive }}
  }}}}
  child {node {Partial }
    child {node {High }
    child {node {Hybrid }
         child {node {Mid-Level }
        child {node [bottom color=blue!40]  {Moderate Executive }}
  }}}}
    child {node {Full }
    child {node {Large-Sized }
    child {node {Weak }
         child {node {Low}
        child {node [bottom color=blue!40]  {Weak Executive  }  } 
  }}}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make sure your code compiles before posting. Also, post a **minimal** working example. You have a lot of packages loaded (some more than once) that aren't used. You'll get better assistance when your MWE illustrates the question you're asking and nothing else.

Comment: I removed most of the unnecessary code from your MWE.

Comment: I wonder and admire too, why you persist on the way, how you ask your question after all received answer to your similar question, which all advise to use `forest`  instead pure `tikz` solution and which  you accepted, but them but it seems after this never use.  So why you accept them? Is this a trick, da people do your task instead of you?

Comment: I am using several graphs in my paper. Most of them use the forest package, but this one looks very good and I already had it before asking my question and do not want to change it. I just need to shorten the arrows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that this answer will help you since so far you not use any of answer on similar questions (which actually are only small variations of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/623695/moving-a-box-in-a-forest-tree-diagram-to-the-middle)) ...

Anyway, for exercise and fun one more answer, which use `forest` package instead Ti*k*Z `tree` package. It is small variation of the @Sandy G answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                shadows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = { % <---
% nodes style
    draw, semithick,
    minimum height=4ex, text width=9em, 
    font=\sffamily,
    text centered,
    drop shadow,
where n children = 0{top color=white,
                     bottom color=blue!50}  % bottoms nodes
                    {fill=green!30},        % others
% edges style
    edge = {-Straight Barb, semithick},
% tree style
    s sep = 3mm, % horizontal distances between nodes
where n children = 3{fill=red!30,   % <---
                     rounded corners=2pt, 
                     l sep=12mm}  % vertical distances at top
                    {rounded corners=2ex,
                     l sep=4mm},  % vertical distances at other levels
%    grow south  % default direction
        }
[Oil Wealth
    [No
        [Low
            [Strong
                [Great
                    [Strong Executive]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    [Partial[High[Hybrid[Mid-Level[Moderate Executive]]]]]
    [Full[Large-Sized[Weak[Low[Weak Executive]]]]]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
To nodes in above MWE are added shadows and two colors to nodes at bottom of tree.

Comment: Thank you.  It seems I must use the forest package every time. I had this nice graph already and did not want to change the package, but just shorten the arrows.

Comment: well, than my answer nor other is not for you. I only not understand why then you accept such answers ...

Comment: I accept them because I have used the forest package in almost every graph except for this one. Perhaps I will now use the forest package for every graph

Answer (score 2):

You can change the `sibling distance` to 5cm (for example) to narrow your tree. On the other hand, you were loading `forest` but not using it. I suggest the following simplified code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[Oil Wealth, fill=red!30, rounded corners=2pt, minimum width=3cm,
    for tree={draw, font=\sffamily, minimum height=3.5ex, drop shadow, edge=-latex, s sep=1cm, l=1.2cm}, 
    for descendants={rounded corners=6pt, fill=green!60, minimum width=10em}, 
    for leaves={fill=blue!40}
    [No[Low[Strong[Great[Strong Executive]]]]]
    [Partial[High[Hybrid[Mid-Level[Moderate Executive]]]]]
    [Full[Large-Sized[Weak[Low[Weak Executive]]]]]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Which will produce the following:
[image]

You can change the spacing in the `for tree` keys. `l=1.2cm` controls the vertical spacing, and `s sep=1cm` controls the horizontal spacing.

Answer (score 1):

If you persist to use Ti*k*Z trees you should read package documentation. Meaning of `sibling distance` and `level distance` is described on the page 82:

> The level distance tells TikZ the distance between (the centers of)
> the nodes on adjacent levels or layers of a tree. The sibling distance
> is, as the name suggests, the distance between (the centers of)
> siblings of the tree.

and illustrated and detailed described  in the section *21.5.2 Default Growth Function*, page 336.

In your case this mean, that sibling distance had to be greater than `text width` + `2*(inner sep)`, i.e.: about 11em, and level distance about 8mm. This size you can change/adjust as you wish. It may also help make nodes a bit narrows. A try of this see in MWE below.

Both distance you can define separately for each tree level by using

```
level 1/.style = {...}
```

See, if the following MWE, which I a wee bit improve, i.e. change style definitions, fulfil your requirements:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows, arrows.meta}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  basic/.style={
    draw,
    rounded corners=6pt,
    text width=9em,
    align=center,
    font=\sffamily,
    drop shadow,
  },
  root/.style={
    basic,
    rounded corners=2pt,
    text width=6em,
    fill=red!30
  },
  child node/.style={
    basic,
    fill=green!60,
    anchor=north
  },
}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  edge from parent/.style={draw, -Latex},
  sibling distance=11em,                    % <===
level 1/.style = {level distance = 12mm,
                  nodes={child node}},      % <---
level 2/.style = {level distance =  8mm},   % <---
level 5/.append style = {nodes={child node, bottom color=blue!40}},     % <---
                    ]
% root, level 1
\node [root] (root) {Oil Wealth}
  child {node {No}
    child {node {Low}
        child {node {Strong}
            child {node {Great}
                child {node {Strong Executive}}
  }}}}
  child {node {Partial}
    child {node {High}
        child {node {Hybrid}
            child {node {Mid-Level}
                child {node {Moderate Executive}}
  }}}}
  child {node {Full }
    child {node {Large-Sized }
        child {node {Weak }
            child {node {Low}
                child {node {Weak Executive}}
  }}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which produce:

[image]

(redlines indicate text borders)

From comparison of above solution and proposed solution in the my first answer is clearly see advantage of `forest` package. Not only that the tree code is much shorter, but the defining of distances between nodes is simpler and more powerful. At `forest` with `s sep` is determined the closed distance between borders of nodes (this are usually at bottom of tree) and with `l sep` distance between tree levels. This distances can be changed for particular levels of tree as is done in the first answer.

In the both cases is  very advisable to read package's documentation :-)